# Bitstream encryption

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

I have a question related to bitstream encryption using eFUSE option. If my FPGA has bitstream encryption key stored in the eFUSE, how Vivado will know the encryption key when generating new encrypted bitstream? Does Vivado has a method to readback the key from eFUSE and use it for encryption?

Comment: https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=bitstream+encryption+using+eFUSE&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vivado uses the `BITSTREAM.ENCRYPTION.KEY0` property (also available in the project settings UI) to specify the encryption key. Obviously you must set this to match what was blown into the eFUSE.

The complete workflow is spelled out pretty clearly in Xilinx Application Note [XAPP1239](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/xapp1239-fpga-bitstream-encryption).